# Full text weighting

Tags: oracle, full-text-search

I have the following tables:

```
create table records
(
  record_id int primary key,
  title varchar(250)
);

create table paragraphs
(
  record_id int primary key,
  paragraph varchar(4000)
)
```

A record may have 1 or more paragraphs. Both title and paragraph are full text search indexed. Title should be weighted higher than paragraphs (user input).

The query I have is as follows:

```
select tbl1.*, tbl2.score as title_score, tbl3.score as paragraph_score from records tbl1 
left outer join 
(
   select score(1) as score from recordswhere contains(title, 'test*5', 1) > 0 
) tbl2 on tbl2.record_id = tbl1.record_id
left outer join
(
   select sum(score(1)) as score from paragraphs where contains(paragraph, 'test*2', 1) > 0 group by record_id
) tbl3 on tbl3.record_id = tbl1.record_id
where (tbl2.score > 0 OR tbl3.score > 0)
```

The left outer joins are needed because either title or paragraph could have the search term.

The problem is that the more paragraphs there is, the higher it scores even though title
is supposed to be weighted higher.

What is the best way to fix this?

Comment: How about using a multiplier on the title_score, i.e. 100 ?

Comment: Would it help to normalise the scores from the paragraphs - so that the SUM doesn't unfairly advantage them - e.g. `select sum(score(1)) / count(*) as score from paragraphs...`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify how Oracle Text scores results you should look into [Alternative and User-Defined Scoring](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/text.111/b28303/query.htm#i1007605). This will give you different scoring for all parts of the application in one place, rather than forcing you to maintain this modified scoring in all the different areas of your application.